# Javascript for round-corner image that doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that works fine in IE9 and Firefox, but not in Chrome. I'd like some advice to fix this issue.

I'm trying a cool trick to round the corner of images that I learned from http://www.bram.us/sandbox/roundedcorners/. I updated my css and included the javascript as in the above site, but actually all images disappear on Chrome while the other two browsers renders the rounded corners as intended.

I know this script works on Chrome as well, since http://www.bram.us/sandbox/roundedcorners/ works fine on Chrome.

Here is the javascript.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('img').wrap(function() {
        return '<span style="background-image:url(' + $(this).attr('src') + '); height: '+ $(this).height() + 'px; width: '+ $(this).width() + 'px;" class="rounded" />';
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can I ask why you don't just use CSS to round the corners? Chrome has great support for `border-radius`.

Comment: You are right. I removed the javascript and instead changed the CSS for the img tag, and then it works on all browsers. Thanks!

Comment: @javvva I've moved my suggestion to the section below as an answer, also including a reference to a great site for any CSS3 issues like this you might encounter in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't forget to include any of these in your css for the `.rounded` class?

`-webkit-border-radius`

`border-radius`

`display: block` or `display:inline-block`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I did include all three lines you mentioned above, but it didn't work on Chrome with the javascript. When I removed the javascript and used border-radius for the img tag, it started working in all browser types.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has great native support for rounding images with CSS. I would suggest avoiding JavaScript here, and instead go with something like the following:

```
img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
    border-radius: 12px;         /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, 
                                    FF4+, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
}
```

The above can be found on [css3please.com](http://css3please.com/).